# Annotate an annotation as an entry point in IntelliJ IDEA without modifying profile

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Assume we have an annotation that is used to mark methods, possibly private, for use by a framework. For example:

```
class Foo {
    @Serializer
    private String serialize() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The method is only ever called by the framework, so it gets marked as **Unused declaration** by IntelliJ IDEA.

I could suppress this warning for myself by adding the hypothetical `@Serializer` annotation to **Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Java > Declaration redundancy > Unused declaration > Options > Entry points > Annotations... > Mark as entry point if annotated by**.

The question is, can I somehow "annotate" the hypothetical `@Serializer` annotation itself so that IntelliJ knows that it marks an entry point, without having to share a full IntelliJ profile with other people or tell them to modify their profile?

I tried adding `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` to the annotation, but as I expected, that had no effect. Presumably because it suppresses the warning on the annotation itself, not the methods that are annotated with it.

Having `Foo` implement an interface that specifies (again, hypothetical) `serialize()` is not an option, since the class should have an option of keeping the method private.

Comment: Seems it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @y.bedrov: Thanks for the suggestion. Created [IDEA-198378](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198378) on YouTrack.

Comment: What about adding this entry point via a custom plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Annotating with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` seems to work now (Intellij 2021.1). I successfully tested it on method and class level.